# How can I send a message on this site?

Tags: discussion, private-messaging

I want to send a message to a user who probably resolved my question to get information. However, I wasn't able to see the "send message" option. Isn't there an option like this?

Comment: You can lave a comment on their answer, but this should be asked on the "meta" site, not here.

Comment: Thanks I'm heading meta section.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about the website in general should be asked on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. With that said, there is no way to currently message another user, but you could always visit the chat room or just comment on his answer.

Thanks.